# Angular controller is not registered error

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I am using the 1.6 version of it.

I have this `apptest.js` script:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

(function(){
    "use strict";
    myApp.controller("productController", function($scope, $http)

    {
        $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(prd)
        {
            $scope.prd = prd.data;
        });
    });
});
```

And here my `data/data.json` data:

```
[
  {
    "id":"1",
    "title":"20 Foot Equipment Trailer",
    "description":"2013 rainbow trailer 20 feet x 82 inch deck area, two 5,000 lb axels, electric brakes, two pull out ramps, break away box, spare tire.",
    "price":6000,
    "posted":"2015-10-24",
    "contact": {
      "name":"John Doe",
      "phone":"(555) 555-5555",
      "email":"johndoe@gmail.com"
    },
    "categories":[
      "Vehicles",
      "Parts and Accessories"
    ],
    "image": "http://www.louisianasportsman.com/classifieds/pics/p1358549934434943.jpg",
    "views":213
  }
]
```

Now here is my html page where I specified the ng-app and ng-controller:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="productController">
<div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Add <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="product in prd">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">{{product.title}}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img ng-src="{{product.image}}">
                {{product.price | currency}}
                {{product.description}}
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">a</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/appTest.js"></script>
</body>
```

I am still getting the following error which is new for me:

> angular.js:14239 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the
>   name 'productController' is not registered.
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.0-rc.0/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=productController

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your IIFE isn't being invoked, you should change it to `(function () {...})();` you must add the `()` to the closure function so that it will be called and then your controller will be registered.

Comment: Can you explain why we use IIFE now in angular ? Please, it is blur to me.

Comment: It's a javascript issue actually, IIFE means Immediatly Invoked Function Expression, its purpose is mostly for code isolation from the root `window` object, once you use an IIFE all declarations are restricted to that scope. It's basicaly all about scope isolation. Check this wikipedia article about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Thanks sir I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its because of your `Immediately Invoked Function Expression`. you have to change it like below :

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

(function(app){
  "use strict";
  app.controller("productController", function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data/data.json').then(function(prd){
      $scope.prd = prd.data;
    });
  });
})(myApp);
```

Comment: context is myApp not app

Comment: yes i think you are misspell `App` instead of `myApp` in parameter isn't it ?

Comment: no, i didn't mis spell it. I am passing `myApp` as argument so i can use any variable alias inside self invoking function.

Answer (score 22):

Just import the file in `index.html`,

```
<script src=".../productController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please do not post identical answers to different questions -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460755/error-controllerctrlreg-a-controller-with-this-name-is-not-registered** Besides that, the whole point by using a generator and grunt is to get rid of manual insertion of scripts to index.html

Comment: thanks for guidance...i used gulp to get rid of manual insertion

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was missing reference in index page as well as my controller name was `startupController` (notice lower case s) and I was trying to register it with `StartupController` (upper case s)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with this same error, I failed to identify the app module in the ng-app directive like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-app>
```

In some circumstances I've seen where ng-app is by itself but I was forced to identify the app like:

`<div class="row" ng-app="myApp">`

Answer (score 2):

In My case, I just copied a piece of code [from an example](https://codepen.io/Crackeraki/pen/zvWqJM), and it contained another `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in one of its  `<DIV>`. The message was initially confusing, as the required controller had the name `Ctrl`

[image]

> If you are reading this, check the name of the controller not found on your web browser console. Mine was `Ctrl`

So, I realized that my structure had another controller named like this one:

**Bad Code**

```html
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>

<!-- SEE THIS TABLE HAS A CONTROLLER WITH A VERY UNDEFINED NAME, SO IT MAKES IT DIFFICULT TO TRACK -->

 <table ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl" >
  <td>
  <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
   <div class="cropArea">
    <ui-cropper image="myImage" area-type="rectangle" aspect-ratio="1.7" result-image="myCroppedImage" result-image-size='{w: 340,h: 200}' init-max-area="true">
     </ui-cropper>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div>Cropped Image:</div>
  <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
  </td>
 </table>
</body>

<script>

  var myApp = angular.module("sampleApp", []);
  
  myApp.controller("SampleCtrl", function ($scope) {

   $scope.message = "It Works!";
   
  });
  
</script>
```

**SOLUTION**

After removing the controller and app definition not initially desired, it worked like a charm.

```html
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
<h1>{{message}}</h1>

<!-- SEE THE NOW DOES NOT HAVE A CONTROLLER, THE CONTROLLER WILL BE MY DEFAULT APP CONTROLLER SampleCtrl -->

 <table>
  <td>
  <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
   <div class="cropArea">
    <ui-cropper image="myImage" area-type="rectangle" aspect-ratio="1.7" result-image="myCroppedImage" result-image-size='{w: 340,h: 200}' init-max-area="true">
     </ui-cropper>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div>Cropped Image:</div>
  <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
  </td>
 </table>
</body>

<script>

  var myApp = angular.module("sampleApp", []);
  
  myApp.controller("SampleCtrl", function ($scope) {

   $scope.message = "It Works!";
   
  });

   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. 
I solved the problem by puting the js code in the main js.
my html is a layer on the main html 
my original html and js are following :

```
<div style="background: #f5f5f5;" ng-app='myapp'  ng-controller="cIdentityCtrl as ctrl">
    <form class="padding-md" name="staffForm" ng-submit="submit()">
        <div class="row popup" style="padding-bottom: 10px;" ng-repeat="item in sfList">
            <label style="width: 130px;text-align: right;"> {{item.branchName}}:</label>
            <input type="text" style="width: 175px;display: inline-block;" class="form-control" ng-model="item.PERCENT"
                   placeholder="股份比例">%
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="height50"></div>
        <div class="text-center iframe-layer-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="staffForm.$invalid">保存</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">关闭</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
var myapp= angular.module('myapp',[]);
    (function(myapp){
        "use strict";
        myapp.service('layerService', layerService)
        .factory('instance', instance);
        myapp.controller('cIdentityCtrl', function($scope, instance, layerService) {
            console.log(instance.storeList)
            $scope.sfList = angular.copy(instance.storeList);
            $scope.submit = function(){
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.sfList.length;i++){
                    if($scope.sfList[i].PERCENT!=null && $scope.sfList[i].PERCENT!=''){
                        if(!/^(((\d|[1-9]\d)(\.\d{1,2})?)|100|100.0|100.00)$/.test($scope.sfList[i].PERCENT)){
                            massage.error($scope.sfList[i].branchName+'门店设置有误:[0,100]保留二位小数');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                instance.fnsf($scope.sfList);
                layerService.close(instance.layero1);
            }

            $scope.close=function(){
                layerService.close(instance.layero1);
            }
        });

    })(myapp);
</script>
```

this html and js opened by ng-include ,but can not find the controller . and I put the js in the parent html`s js file and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and found the reason as...
The app module in the ng-app directive was defined/used at body-tag level like this

> `<body ng-app="intervalAngularExample">`

and the $controller definition in productionController.js was imported in the html file at header level, certainly that should not work.

> ```
> <head>
> <script src=".../productController.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body ng-app="intervalAngularExample">
> </body>
> ```

import should be then inside the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the $controller() service is called with a string that does not match any of the registered controllers. The controller service may have been invoked directly, or indirectly, for example through the ngController directive, or inside a component / directive / route definition (when using a string for the controller property). Third-party modules can also instantiate controllers with the $controller() service

Causes for this error can be:

1- Your reference to the controller has a typo. For example, in the ngController directive attribute, in a component definition's controller property, or in the call to $controller().

2- You have not registered the controller (neither via Module.controller nor $controllerProvider.register().

3- You have a typo in the registered controller name.

ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=GreetingController