# Error: $controller:ctrlreg A controller with this name is not registered

Tags: angularjs

I see this error when I press F12 in chrome, but strangely things still work. There seems to be no problems.

```
The controller with the name 'AccountUpdateViewModel' is not registered.
```

Here is my js file. Any idea why? The version of angualr I am using is [1.6.0 from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/angularjs/1.6.0)(I develop on Visual Studio)

```
var accountUpdateModule = angular.module('accountUpdate', ['common', 'ngRoute'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });

        $routeProvider.when(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step1', { templateUrl: Avts.rootPath + 'Templates/AccountUpdate/Step1.html', controller: 'AccountUpdateStep1ViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step2', { templateUrl: Avts.rootPath + 'Templates/AccountUpdate/Step2.html', controller: 'AccountUpdateStep2ViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step3', { templateUrl: Avts.rootPath + 'Templates/AccountUpdate/Step3.html', controller: 'AccountUpdateStep3ViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/confirm', { templateUrl: Avts.rootPath + 'Templates/AccountUpdate/Confirm.html', controller: 'AccountUpdateConfirmViewModel' });
        $routeProvider.when(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/successfullyupdated', { templateUrl: Avts.rootPath + 'Templates/AccountUpdate/Successfull.html', controller: 'AccountUpdateSuccessfullyUpdatedViewModel' });
        // 5:40 Sec. If it does not find any of these steps in this little spa silo, then redirect to step1
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step1' });

    });



accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, viewModelHelper) {
    // Nested ViewModels or sub viewmodels. See Video 138 3:40 Sec
    // Things that are set up here in this view model(AccountRegisterViewModel) is bound to the priticular view Register.cshtml.
    // see 4:50 Sec
    $scope.viewModelHelper = viewModelHelper;
    $scope.accountModelStep1 = new Avts.AccountUpdateModelStep1();
    $scope.accountModelStep2 = new Avts.AccountUpdateModelStep2();
    $scope.accountModelStep3 = new Avts.AccountUpdateModelStep3();


    $scope.fetchDataToUpdate = function () {
        viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/account/update', null,
            function (result) {

                $scope.accountModelStep1.Email = result.data.Email;
                $scope.accountModelStep1.UserName = result.data.UserName;

                $scope.accountModelStep2.FirstName = result.data.FirstName;
                $scope.accountModelStep2.LastName = result.data.LastName;

                $scope.accountModelStep3.Address = result.data.Address;
                $scope.accountModelStep3.City = result.data.City;
                $scope.accountModelStep3.State = result.data.State;
                $scope.accountModelStep3.PostalCode = result.data.PostalCode;

            });
    }

    $scope.fetchDataToUpdate();
    //$scope.previous = function () {
    //    // 6:00 Sec
    //    $window.history.back();
    //}
});

accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateStep1ViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, viewModelHelper, validator) {
    viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = true;
    viewModelHelper.modelErrors = [];

    // No setpup rules for step 1 edit. Just showing Email and userName
    //var accountModelStep1Rules = [];

    //var setupRules = function () {

    //    accountModelStep1Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("Email", {
    //        required: {
    //            message: "Email is required",
    //            email: { message: "Email is not an email." }
    //        }
    //    }));
    //    accountModelStep1Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("Password", {
    //        required: { message: "Password is required" },
    //        minLength: { message: "Password must be at least 6 characters", params: 6 }
    //    }));

        //accountModelStep1Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("PasswordConfirm", {
        //    required: { message: "Password confirmation is required" },
        //    custom: {
        //        validator: Avts.mustEqual, // See 143, 2:30
        //        message: "Password do not match",
        //        params: function () { return $scope.accountModelStep1.Password; } // must be function so it can be obtained on-demand
        //    }
        //}));
    //}

    //$scope.fetchData = function () {
    //    viewModelHelper.apiGet('api/account/edit', null,
    //        function (result) {
    //            $scope.accountModelStep1.Email = result.data.Email;
    //            $scope.accountModelStep1.UserName = result.data.UserName;
    //        });
    //}

    $scope.step2 = function () {
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step2');
        // Video 144
        // Pressing should just do validation and proceed to step 2.
        //validator.ValidateModel($scope.accountModelStep1, accountModelStep1Rules);
        //viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = $scope.accountModelStep1.isValid;
        //viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep1.errors;
        //if (viewModelHelper.modelIsValid) {
        //    viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/account/register/validate1', $scope.accountModelStep1,
        //        function (result) {
        //            // See the video 144 3:35 Sec
        //            $scope.accountModelStep1.Initialized = true;
        //            $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/edit/step2');
        //        },
        //        function (failureResult) {
        //            $scope.accountModelStep1.errors = failureResult.data;
        //            viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep1.errors;
        //            viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = false;
        //        }
        //        );
        //}
        //else
        //    viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep1.errors;
    }

    //setupRules();
    //$scope.fetchData();
});

accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateStep2ViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, viewModelHelper, validator) {

    viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = true;
    viewModelHelper.modelErrors = [];

    var accountModelStep2Rules = [];

    var setupRules = function () {

        accountModelStep2Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("FirstName", {
            required: { message: "First name is required" }
        }));
        accountModelStep2Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("LastName", {
            required: { message: "Last name is required" }
        }));

    }

    // Video 146
    $scope.step3 = function () {
        validator.ValidateModel($scope.accountModelStep2, accountModelStep2Rules);
        viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = $scope.accountModelStep2.isValid;
        viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep2.errors;
        if (viewModelHelper.modelIsValid) {
            viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/account/update/validate2', $scope.accountModelStep2,
                function (result) {
                    $scope.accountModelStep2.Initialized = true;
                    $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step3');
                },
                function (failureResult) {
                    $scope.accountModelStep2.errors = failureResult.data;
                    viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep2.errors;
                    viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = false;
                }
                );
        }
        else
            viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep2.errors;
    }

    $scope.backToStep1 = function () {
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step1');
    }

    setupRules();
});

accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateStep3ViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, viewModelHelper, validator) {

    if (!$scope.accountModelStep2.Initialized) {
        // got to this controller before going through step 2
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step2');
    }

    var accountModelStep3Rules = [];

    var setupRules = function () {

        accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("Address", {
            required: { message: "Address is required" }
        }));
        accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("City", {
            required: { message: "City is required" }
        }));
        accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("State", {
            required: { message: "State is required" }
        }));
        accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("PostalCode", {
            required: { message: "Postal code is required" },
            pattern: { message: "Postal code is in invalid format", params: /^[1-9][0-9]{5}$/ }
        }));

        //accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("CreditCard", {
        //    required: { message: "Credit Card # is required" },
        //    pattern: { message: "Credit card is in invalid format (16 digits)", params: /^\d{16}$/ }
        //}));
        //accountModelStep3Rules.push(new validator.PropertyRule("ExpiryDate", {
        //    required: { message: "Expiration Date is required" },
        //    pattern: { message: "Expiration Date is in invalid format (MM/YY)", params: /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{2}$/ }
        //}));
    }


    $scope.confirm = function () {
        validator.ValidateModel($scope.accountModelStep3, accountModelStep3Rules);
        viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = $scope.accountModelStep3.isValid;
        viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep3.errors;
        if (viewModelHelper.modelIsValid) {
            viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/account/update/validate3', $scope.accountModelStep3,
                function (result) {
                    $scope.accountModelStep3.Initialized = true;
                    $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/confirm');
                },
                function (failureResult) {
                    $scope.accountModelStep3.errors = failureResult.data;
                    viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep3.errors;
                    viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = false;
                }
                );
        }
        else
            viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep3.errors;
    }

    $scope.backToStep2 = function () {
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step2');
    }

    setupRules();
});

accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateConfirmViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, viewModelHelper) {

    if (!$scope.accountModelStep3.Initialized) {
        // got to this controller before going through step 3
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step3');
    }

    $scope.updateAccount = function () {

        // Video 147 2:00 Sec
        var accountModel;

        accountModel = $.extend(accountModel, $scope.accountModelStep1);
        accountModel = $.extend(accountModel, $scope.accountModelStep2);
        accountModel = $.extend(accountModel, $scope.accountModelStep3);

        viewModelHelper.apiPost('api/account/update', accountModel,
            function (result) {
                //$location.path(Avts.rootPath);
                $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/successfullyupdated');
                //account/update/successfullyupdateded
                //account/update/successfullyupdated
                //$window.location.href = Avts.rootPath;
            },
            function (failureResult) {
                $scope.accountModelStep1.errors = failureResult.data;
                viewModelHelper.modelErrors = $scope.accountModelStep1.errors;
                viewModelHelper.modelIsValid = false;
            }
            );
    }

    $scope.backToStep3 = function () {
        $location.path(Avts.rootPath + 'account/update/step3');
    }
});

//AccountUpdateSuccessfullyUpdatedViewModel

accountUpdateModule.controller("AccountUpdateSuccessfullyUpdatedViewModel", function ($scope, $http, $location, $window, viewModelHelper) {

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You had `'AccountUpdateViewModel` controller. but you didn't registered it in your route.config. if you didn't config means you never use it anywhere.

please remove unwanted model. or register it in the rout config section.

Answer (score 2):

i import the file, in `index.html` and my problem solved,

```
<script src=".../AccountUpdateStep1ViewModel.js"></script>
```