# Angular controller ctrlreg error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a ctrlreg error when I try to open a modal dialog. I don't think it's a typo and I do think the controller is being registered, but when I attach to it in the debugger, I don't see the template file.

Here is the controller:

```
    (function () {
    angular.module('myAppName.controllers').controller('ConfirmationModalController', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
        $scope.del = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close(true);
        };
        $scope.keep = function () {
            $uibModalInstance.close(false);
        };
    });

})();
```

That gets hit when I reload the page thus I'm guessing it's being registered.

Now here is how I attempt to create the dialog:

```
    function deleteObject(obj) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/confirm_modal.tpl',
                    controller: 'ConfirmationModalController',
                    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
                    size: 'lg',
                    resolve: {
                        data: function () {
                            return $ctrl.data;
                        }
                    }
                });
    modalInstance.result.then(
                    function(obj)
                    {
                        $ctrl.data.objects = _.without($ctrl.data.objects, obj);
                        DataService.save($ctrl.data);
                        ObjectService.remove(object.id);
                    },
                    function () {
                        console.log("------------ERROR----------");
                    }
            );
}
```

Edit:
Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=ConfirmationModalController
at http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:6:425
at $get (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:92:395)
at http://localhost:8080/webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.2.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js:8:29619
at http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:134:167
at m.$get.m.$eval (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:148:47)
at m.$get.m.$digest (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:145:92)
at m.$get.m.$apply (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:148:341)
at l (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:101:89)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (http://localhost:8080/webjars/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js:106:489) Possibly unhandled rejection: {}
```

Comment: do you get a 404 error for the templateUrl? or it is just not opening?

Comment: No, I get an exception. I'll update the question with the error message

Comment: I think you have an error with your controller scope/visibility. If you change this line `controller: 'ConfirmationModalController',` using an inline controller `function(){}` do you still have the same issue?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720733/angular-controller-is-not-registered-error) SO

Comment: @quirimmo Using inline controller eliminated the issue and the modal was rendered.

Comment: can you show me all the code where you open the modal? module, dependencies how you include them etc etc? if you want we can also switch to a chat

Comment: The code that opens the modal is in the question. I'm including the controller in index.html so it's getting loaded. Not sure what else might be relevant?

Comment: yeah the controller/service where you open the modal. And can you post order the order in the index.html where you include your files? 
It may be relevant.
Actually your issue is that the controller is not recognized when you assign it in the modal, so when you are executing that code, that controller is not registered

Comment: @Jax Not sure what that answer means. How you pass the module should make no difference...

Comment: this is fairly large app so posting the includes will be too much, but for all it's worth, I moved it near the top (it was near the bottom before)

Comment: If your controller is added as `ng-controller`, have you tried to change to `ngController`?