# AngularJS: Controller is not Registered in Testing Environment

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm in the process of upgrading a legacy app that uses `angularjs` to the latest LTS release. I seem to have the application working, but i'm struggling with

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'LogoutController' is not registered.

errors in the test environment.

I have an `angular` `module`:

```
angular
 .module('LoginModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

a controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("LoginModule")
        .controller('LogoutController', LogoutController);

    LogoutController.$inject = ['LogoutService'];

    function LogoutController(LogoutService) {

        this.logout = function () {
            LogoutService.logout();
        };

    }
})();
```

and a spec

```
describe('MyApplication', function () {
    'use strict';

    var ctrl, mockLogoutService;

    beforeEach(module('LoginModule'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.factory('LogoutService', function () {
                return ({
                    logout: jasmine.createSpy('LogoutService.logout')
                });
            });
        });
    });

    describe('LogoutController', function () {

        beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, LogoutService) {
            mockLogoutService = LogoutService;
            ctrl = $controller('LogoutController', {
                LogoutService: mockLogoutService
            });
        }));

        it('instantiates', function () {
            expect(ctrl).not.toBe(undefined);
        });
    });
});
```

When the spec runs, i get

> Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'LogoutController' is not registered.

The files are in a directory structure like:

```
- root
  -angular
    -module
      -login
      -dialog
      -theme
  -test
    -jasmine
      -login
      -dialog
      -theme
```

and i configure `karma` to load files using:

```
files: [
    './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    './node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js',
    './angular/application.js',
    './angular/module/**/*.js',
    './test/jasmine/**/*.js'
],
```

I ran across [Angular controller is not registered error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720733/angular-controller-is-not-registered-error/42053195) suggesting that the IIFE was problematic, so i tried implementing the accepted answer without joy -- which make sense, as the project has a couple dozen other controllers wrapped in IIFE that all test without needing changes.

So i'm stumped, and am left wondering if i've been starting at the code too long to see something right in front of my face. Looking for any insight into why this code produces the "controller not registered" error.

Comment: Check to see that you have included the controller in your test runner files list

Comment: @codymikol Edited the relevant karma configuration infor into post